# Connection between Node.js, TypeScript, JavaScript and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

I apologize if this question was asked before - until now I have not found a sufficient answer.

**My Question**
What is the connection between Node.js and TypeScript? Or TypeScript and Angular?

I understand that **TypeScript is a language that extends the functionality of Javascript**, but what does **Node.js do**? Is it something like TypeScript? If so, then both can not be used simultanously, can they?

And what does Angular do? I know that you can build native web application for any platform with Angular but what is Angulars part?

My current abilities:
I know Java and have currently learned HTML, CSS and JavaScript in order to build a single-page application that can run on most systems.

Comment: `AngularJs` is a framework written in Javascript.
`Typescript` is a typed transpiler for javascirpt.
`Node.js` is javascript server side (running javascript on server instead of client like browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is an extension of javascript. It helps you type better understanding code which "compiles" into functioning javascript code for it to run. It can be used in every project that also can be written in javascript. Typescript is javascript. nodeJS is a javascript interpreter. Angular is a javascript front-end framework. Three completely different things. Angular can be used for the front-end and nodeJS for the backend while you can write a typescript application to be run by nodeJS.

I realized after writing the answer that this is still not clear enough. Javascript is not a compiled language. It could only run by the browsers until 2009 that nodeJS was created. NodeJS is a c++ application that reads and **EXECUTES** javascript.

Comment: So I can install Node.js as the interpreter for my project that can be used in any IDE I want. Then I can use TypeScript for my project, because it is "better" than JavaScript, as language. And Angular is the framework that helps me to turn my project in native applications for the iOS/Android/Web?

Comment: Node can be used to create an http server. You can create a mobile application with node. Node is really just there to allow you to create javascript applications that are not just website applications run on your browser. Writing in typescript instead of native javascript is your choice but I do not recommend it if you are new to javascript. You should first learn how javascript works and behaves and then try some other variant. Angular helps you create the design. Their motto is " Angular is what html would be if it was created for dynamic web applications. "

Comment: Now, and with **Wax** comment, I understand, what Node.js really is.
I have chosen to start with TypeScript because it was recommended to me by various people - even the Angular team itself suggests TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS is for the frontend side of your system. Node JS is simply a Javascript runtime environment, just like Java, where you can run your own server with Java Runtime Environment (JRE) on a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

If you are curious about building cross platform apps, Angular Ionic might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Now I do understand it.

I have a specific task to solve: 
I have to create a native application that can be used to scan barcodes of items in a storage and can write the information in the PostgreSQL database of our companies ERP system. 
Do you think that Ionic is the right framework for this task?

Comment: a mobile application?